# ggplot: Determining breaks for continuous data in geo_map() call

Tags: r, dictionary, ggplot2

Hopefully this is simple:
I am working on a choropleth map with ggplot.

How can I pass the breaks (quantiles, jenks and such) for a continuous variable being mapped, as opposed to relying on the default gradient? I would ideally like to use the output from `classIntervals` and pass that as an aesthetic, but I tried `scale_y_continuous` but that scales the map frame itself and not the fill variable being mapped.

So, how to pass breaks, and which form do they take?

Comment: If it is the `fill` variable you are trying to adjust, use `scale_fill_continuous` (or some other variant of `scale_fill_...`